# Entity Framework Core 3.1.1 : Where query could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated,

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework-core, aspnetboilerplate, ef-core-3.1

After I upgraded Entity Framework Core from 2 to 3.0.0 and 3.1.1, my code broke on Linq `.Where` clauses.

I wouldn't use `.AsEnumerable<ExampleObject()`.

For example:

```
List<string> exampleFilter = new List<string>(){"filter1" , "filter2"};

var IQueryable<ExampleObjects> objs = repository.GetAll().Where(wh => exampleFilter.Contains(wh.Name));//HERE1

// here code broke in v3.0.0 when apply where with contains
var count = await objs.CountAsync();
```

After upgrade 3.0.0 to 3.1.1 the last bug was solved but now my code broke a few lines down:

```
objs = objs.Where(wh => MatchFilters(wh.Name, wh.Description,filters));

// here the code broke in v3.1.1
count = await objs.CountAsync();
```

This is my exception:

> Where(a => ClassName.MatchEveryFilter(
> name: a.Name,
> code: a.Code,
> filters: __filters_0))'
> could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either
> AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync()

My code:

```
private bool MatchFilters(string name, strin description , List<strings> filters)
{
    foreach(var filter in filters)
    {
        if(!name.Contains(filter) && !description.Contains(filer))
             return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

How can I rewrite my code on where with function `MatchFilters` inside?

Answer (score 1):

you could chain your filters

```
var query = context.TableName.AsQueryable();

foreach(var filter in filters)
{
    query = query.Where(x => !x.Name.Contains(filter) && !x.Description.Contains(filter))
}

var result = query.ToList();
```